# Smell/s plural or singular?

Tags: singular-vs-plural

Should I use the plural of 'smell' in this sentence?

- > Ensure that your kitchen is free from any offensive smell, such as garlic.
- > Ensure that your kitchen is free from any offensive smells, such as garlic.

Answer (score 2):

"**Such as**" indicates that there ***may be*** more than one smell. Use the plural.

Comment: I don't think so. Could you add some more detail to *such as..* that *always* have plural following it? Why I think like that is I feel that in such instances, 'such as' serves as 'like' and it *can*  be followed by a singular as well.

Comment: @MaulikV: "Like" would be incorrect here, or at least insufferably colloquial.

Comment: I know the subtle difference. But from the given context, *both* are possible.

Comment: @MaulikV: Not really.